# SSMS 18.2 cannot create database diagram

Tags: sql-server

As the title say, my SQL Server Management Studio cannot create database diagram as it keep show me an error is Index was outside the bounds of the array. How can I solve it?

This is my SSMS version

SQL Server Management Studio                        15.0.18142.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools                        15.0.1389.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)                     10.0.18362.1
Microsoft MSXML                     3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                     9.11.18362.0
Microsoft .NET Framework                        4.0.30319.42000
Operating System                        10.0.18362

Comment: What steps did you follow the create the diagram? What is the full text of the error?

Comment: @music2myear I have 2 table in the database and build the relationship between them. When I want to build a database diagram, I create that and it show ```Index was outside the bounds of the array```

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the Microsoft SQL server solved the problem for me.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Simply closing and restarting SSMS v18.12.1 worked for me, too.